# Toilet water supply valve facing down instead of up

Tags: plumbing, valve

I replaced the pipe leading into the toilet water supply valve, but when I did I made it so that the threaded PVC part that connects with the valve forces the valve outlet to face down instead of up when I screw on the valve. Is there any way to fix this? Or is it ok to have it facing down, other than needing a longer line to the toilet?

Comment: Can you add a picture?  Your situation isn't clear, ie what is forcing what and how?  FWIW, the only problem I ever had with supply valve orientation was when the valve *handle* was on the bottom.  The screw holding on the handle was not stainless, so by being on the bottom it collected condensation, rusted away and the handle fell off.

Answer (score 4):

A threaded fitting should be able to be turned half way without leaking.

Either loosen it one half turn or tighten one half turn.  I would try to loosen it first if it is on quite tight already. Some people think they need to be tighten as much as possible to not leak, but usually they don't.

Can also just leave it and use a long enough hose/line so the line is not kinked.